# É possível criar um servidor remoto com MongoDB? De que maneira?

Tags: banco-de-dados, mongodb

A minha dúvida, para ser mais claro, se trata em criar um servidor com mongodb em uma hospedagem cloud (por exemplo) e acessa-la através de um outro servidor.

Exemplo:
Tenho uma app mobile.
Hospedei meu mongoDB numa hospedagem cloud (ubuntu).
Quero conectar minha app ao db no servidor cloud.

**Isto é possível? De que maneira?**

Eu estou ingressando neste aprendizado e a minha dúvida foi justamente criar um servidor com MongoDB de uma maneira que eu poderia acessa-lo remotamente.
Fora do "localhost", entendem? Diferente de todos os tutoriais que eu vi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Desconsiderando as questões de firewall e segurança, a lógica para a conexão remota de um MongoDB para um MySQL, por exemplo, é a mesma.

No seu terminal, por sua vez, você vai usar o seguinte fragmento para fazer a conexão:

```
./mongo 192.168.0.1:27017
```

Se o IP ou o endereço do servidor estiver disponível e dentro dos conformes, a conexão vai ser feita com sucesso.

Em outras palavras, você vai levantar o banco de dados no seu cloud que está rodando fantasiosamente sobre o IP `195.198.5.10`. Então, pra acessar esse "driver", você precisa somente apontar o acesso à `195.198.5.10`. Por exemplo:

```
./mongo 195.198.5.10
```

Tecnicamente falando, se você tem uma aplicação, usará este endereço de IP para indicar onde o banco está localizado.